# Search DateFields by Format A in Django Admin though they are stored in Format B

Tags: django, django-admin

Am building a Django app. And on the admin is is required to be able to search for items based on queries that might also include names of the month, year, etc.

The problem (I can't seem to find a solution to this on SO or elsewhere), is that the default format for dates in Django (ok, the way the dates have been persisted to the datastore) is %Y-%m-%d, but I wish to be able to search on say query like "June" from the Django Admin search.

How do I make it possible to search date fields using custom date formats, without converting the formats in which the dates are persisted?

Answer (score 0):

Date and Time are stored in the database as a distinct type for them, because you should be able to do special date time operations like greater than, lesser than and not just string search.

Django ORM accepts the date-time as strings formatted in one of the standard formats including strings, integers and `datetime` objects .

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

or

```
Entry.objects.filter(
...     headline__startswith='What'
... ).exclude(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime.now()
... ).filter(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 1)
... )
```

You could use any one of the several libraries to parse the time in the string to `datetime` 
 objects. The easiest would be to use the awesome [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library:

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('2008-08-09T18:39:22Z')
#Following is returned
datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 9, 18, 39, 22, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: thanks Lakshman, but the problem is not parsing the datetime objects -- that I can already do, but enabling the user of the in-built django admin search to be able to search for an item whose date is `2010-5-4` in the db table by typing query `'May'` in the search box. The problem is on how to inform the search engine to pick results by date queries of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found the answer but it could be useful to someone (like myself!) still looking into this.

**Django 1.6+** :
You can customise the search results:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

**Previous Django versions**:
You just need to use your own ChangeList to temporary change the date format in the query string. Note that the format is only changed temporarily so that the user won't see any change in the query string.

The example here below accepts UK date format, e.g. '31 Dec 1999' but it can easily changed to accept any date format (or just a month name like 'June' as requested by @nemesisfixx)

In your admin model customise the changelist class:

```
  class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
     def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns the ChangeList class for use on the changelist page.
        """
        return MyChangeList
```

Then in MyChangeList class:

```
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):
def get_query_set(self, request):
    # Allow date search with UK format
    try:
        date_search = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.query, '%d %b %Y').date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        date_search = self.query
    with temporary_value(self, 'query', date_search):
        qs = super(MyChangeList, self).get_query_set(request)
        return qs
```